# issue to run ios app from appium

Tags: ios, appium, instruments

I'm trying to run an iOS app with appium i've searched several examples on internet and this is with what i've come out :

```
public class NotAScenario {

    IOSDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void start() throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.3");
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "mydevicename");
        caps.setCapability("app", "myipafile.ipa");
        driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        sleep(5000);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void end() throws InterruptedException {
        sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("test");
        sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

I tried with an real device iphone 5S, I tried with a simulator same result the app just open/close in 0.5 sec in a loop then it crashes and I get this error

```
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to launch instruments, this is try #1

[Instruments] Launching instruments

[debug] [Instruments] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 'myudid'
[debug] [Instruments] Found Insruments-Without-Delay: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7
[debug] [Instruments] Spawning instruments with command: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /var/folders/sw/w9bk_9_96s1bwz15mzxk3qpd7lj5f9/T/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w myudid my.app.package -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/mobileautomation/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-bbff984e2d53a4ae.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /var/folders/sw/w9bk_9_96s1bwz15mzxk3qpd7lj5f9/T/appium-instruments'
[debug] [Instruments] And extra without-delay env: {}
[debug] [Instruments] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status - - ms - -

[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status - - ms - -

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug my.app.package was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).

[debug] [Instruments] Instruments exited with code 253

[Instruments] Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup
```

I've tried to run it from my code, I tried to run it directly from appium and I even tried to run it from Instruments/Automation but I keep on having the same result the :

```
[INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Permission to debug my.app.package was denied. The app must be signed with a development identity (e.g. iOS Developer).
```

I've seen in here that it can be related to the fact that the build is in "Release" and not in "Debug" so I asked the dev team to give me a debug build but I still have the same result.

Could it be that they didn't build it the right way ?

Am I missing something ? Do they need the device name / udid in an allowed file or something ?

EDIT :

I did receive a new build of the dev it was indeed an issue with the provisionning profile that was not in dev & the build settings not in debug

Comment: > The app must be signed with a development identity

Answer (score 0):

Please use debug build of the app , this problem is due to not using debug build ,you need debug build on iOS in order to automate and make sure ui automation is enabled in developer options

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to below folder 
   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform"
2. I found a folder named (11.2) & My real device version was (11.2.5)
3. Just Renamed the folder with version name (11.2) -> (11.2.5).

Started working again from me.